# Read text from a .txt file and insert a string using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text

Okay so long story short I want to read a .txt file into my program and then insert a string at a specific point in the text. The output would look something along the lines of this:

"text from file {string} more text from file"

This is the relevant code I'm currently working with:

```
with open(r"act 1 text\act_1_scene_1_talk.txt","r+") as scene_1_talk_file:
    scene_1_talk = scene_1_talk_file.read()
print(input("Press enter to continue. "))
print(f"{scene_1_talk}")
```

I suppose I could just cut the text file in half and then put the string in between it, but I would prefer to keep the file in one body. I can provide additional code segments to help clarify anything.

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*? What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to put your `{string}` at, like, middle of the text file. Then you can

```
with open('note.txt', "r") as f:
    f_read = f.read()
middle_position = int(len(f_read) / 2) - 1 //minus one because array starts from zero
//strings are immutable, so we need another variable to store the new string
result = f_read[:middle_position] + "{string}" + f_read[middle_position:]
print(result)
```